# The GroupHeaderTemplate affects the height of the Items in the CollectionView in Xamarin Forms while using MeasureFirstItem Strategy

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, maui

I have a simple `CollectionView` which will be displaying images and I want them to be the same size (e.g. 60 units) and they are grouped as well. Since I wanted the scrolling performance to be good I used `ItemSizingStrategy="MeasureFirstItem"` but then the height of the images ended up the same as the header.

This simple CollectionView shows this problem, where we are showing `Label`s with grouping.

```
<CollectionView 
    x:Name="CollectionViewTempalte"
    ItemSizingStrategy="MeasureFirstItem"
    IsGrouped="True"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">

    <CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="textcollectionview:GroupSampleDate">
            <StackLayout  Orientation="Vertical">
                <Label Text="Group Header" />
            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>

    <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" Span="4" VerticalItemSpacing="1" HorizontalItemSpacing="1"/>
    </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>

    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="textcollectionview:SampelData">
            <Grid Padding="2" BackgroundColor="Red">
                <Grid HorizontalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="86" WidthRequest="86" BackgroundColor="Yellow">
                    <Label Text="Hey There" BackgroundColor="Green"></Label>
                </Grid>               
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

</CollectionView>
```

I don't know why but the `CollectionView` is selecting the header as the first item and setting the `Height` of the items to the `Height` of the header.

It works if I set the `ItemSizingStrategy="MeasureAllItems"` but I want to know how to make it work with `MeasureFirstItem`.

I also found this in issues https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/8467 but there was no answer there.

Comment: I've looked through Xamarin Forms source code used by CollectionView. Unfortunately, the code that measures items is deep in a base class, that does not understand grouped items. At that place in code, the group header looks just like any other child element of the view. Equally bad, its in platform-specific code, so can't be fixed in cross-platform code. I doubt this will get fixed in XF. For Maui, there is no point in anyone attempting this fix until general performance improvements are done. If MeasureAll gets fast enough, then this becomes moot.

Comment: For now, put fixed HeightRequest and WidthRequest on the outermost layout in your ItemTemplate. Hopefully this will speed up MeasureAllItems: `<Grid Padding="2" HeightRequest="90" ...>`. **BTW, you could test whether MeasureFirstItem really makes that much difference in your case.** Put the same HeightRequest on your header, so that it is the same height. I know this isn't the appearance you want, but it will let you compare performance.

Comment: Is it on android? I test it on ios and it works fine.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I checked with MeasureFirstItem and it does help but it's not way better. Thanks for looking into it 

Comment: @AdrainZhu-MSFT Yes it is on android.